# Detect keyboard layout in iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]` I can get an array of the phone's preffered and supported languages. What is the equivalient for getting an array with the phone's preffered keyboard layouts?

Comment: The keyboard layouts are set by you for each textfield/view. If have a textfield which is for entering an url, then you'll set the textfield's keyboard type for URL input.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to know that?

Comment: @fzwo: I am using a web based API that takes a language parameter. So I need to find the first supported language in the defaults. But the API supports a few languages that are not supported in the iPhone display language, but that are supported as keyboard layouts. So since the keyboard layout offers a richer language default I want to inspect it to see which language the user truly prefers.